# How to solve for a pesky syntax error with my new column in my .apply() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to recategorize a series of strings that represent the number of times an app has been downloaded because it doesn't show the raw number of downloads. I have to group 20 strings into 7 different items and put them in a new column named 'downloads'.

I've tried editing the brackets and parenthesis. I previously used np.apply incorrectly.

```
from pandas import DataFrame 

fear = pd.read_csv('googleplaystore.csv', encoding='latin')

n_ratings = {'Install':['0+', '1+', '5+', '10+', '50+', '100+', '500+', '1,000+', '5,000+', 
             '10,000+', '50,000+', '100,000+', '500,000+', '1,000,000+', '5,000,000+', '10,000,000+', 
             '50,000,000+', '100,000,000+', '500,000,000+', '1,000,000,000+']}
df = DataFrame(n_ratings, columns=['Install'])  

df['downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(lambda x: '0-1k' if x.isin(['0+', '1+', '5+', '10+', '50+', '100+', '500+'])

df['downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(lambda x: '1k-100k' if x.isin(['1,000+', '5,000+', '10,000+', '50,000+']))

df['downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(lambda x: '100k-1M' if x.isin(['100,000+', '500,000+'])

df['downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(lambda x: '1M-10M' if x.isin(['1,000,000+', '5,000,000+'])

df['downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(lambda x: '10M-100M' if x.isin(['10,000,000+', '50,000,000+'])

df['downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(lambda x: '100M-1B' if x.isin(['100,000,000+', '500,000,000+'])

df['downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(lambda x: '> 1B' if x.isin(['1,000,000,000+'])
```

Comment: You need an `else` clause with your `... if ...` construct. It should be `... if ... else ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `apply` or an `if-else` for this. Simply use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for this which you pass `conditions` and based on those conditions you pass it `choices`:

```
conditions = (
    df['Install'].isin(['0+', '1+', '5+', '10+', '50+', '100+', '500+']),
    df['Install'].isin(['1,000+', '5,000+', '10,000+', '50,000+']),
    df['Install'].isin(['100,000+', '500,000+']),
    df['Install'].isin(['1,000,000+', '5,000,000+']),
    df['Install'].isin(['10,000,000+', '50,000,000+']),
    df['Install'].isin(['100,000,000+', '500,000,000+']),
    df['Install'].isin(['1,000,000,000+'])
)

choices = ['0-1k', '1k-100k', '100k-1M', '1M-10M', '10M-100M', '100M-1B', '> 1B']

df['downloads'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='unknown')

print(df)
           Install downloads
0               0+      0-1k
1               1+      0-1k
2               5+      0-1k
3              10+      0-1k
4              50+      0-1k
5             100+      0-1k
6             500+      0-1k
7           1,000+   1k-100k
8           5,000+   1k-100k
9          10,000+   1k-100k
10         50,000+   1k-100k
11        100,000+   100k-1M
12        500,000+   100k-1M
13      1,000,000+    1M-10M
14      5,000,000+    1M-10M
15     10,000,000+  10M-100M
16     50,000,000+  10M-100M
17    100,000,000+   100M-1B
18    500,000,000+   100M-1B
19  1,000,000,000+      > 1B
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use apply, you can just define a function that checks all of the conditions in one block.

```
def classify(x):
    if x in ['0+', '1+', '5+', '10+', '50+', '100+', '500+']:
        return '0-1k'
    elif x in ['1,000+', '5,000+', '10,000+', '50,000+']:
        return '1k-100k'
    elif x in ['100,000+', '500,000+']:
        return '100k-1M' 
    elif x in ['1,000,000+', '5,000,000+']:
        return '1M-10M'
    elif x in ['10,000,000+', '50,000,000+']:
        return '10M-100M' 
    elif x in ['100,000,000+', '500,000,000+']:
        return '100M-1B'
    elif x in ['1,000,000,000+']:
        return '> 1B'
    else:
        return 'error'

df['Downloads'] = df['Install'].apply(classify)

           Install Downloads
0               0+      0-1k
1               1+      0-1k
2               5+      0-1k
3              10+      0-1k
4              50+      0-1k
5             100+      0-1k
6             500+      0-1k
7           1,000+   1k-100k
8           5,000+   1k-100k
9          10,000+   1k-100k
10         50,000+   1k-100k
11        100,000+   100k-1M
12        500,000+   100k-1M
13      1,000,000+    1M-10M
14      5,000,000+    1M-10M
15     10,000,000+  10M-100M
16     50,000,000+  10M-100M
17    100,000,000+   100M-1B
18    500,000,000+   100M-1B
19  1,000,000,000+      > 1B
```